# Simplifying nested parent child code in JS

Tags: javascript

I have very poorly constructed JS code which I need to shorten using do-while or using increment like `for (i=0;i<10;i++)`. The script works fine, but is not pretty on the eyes.

I am trying to export the folder tree structure in VMware into a array of objects with two properties - "Folder Name" and "Folder Path". I use vCenter plugin to query the data. Here's a pic of the inventory -

[image]

Here's the code -

```
function getFolderPath(dc)
{
    var row = [];
    var VcFolders = VcPlugin.getAllVmFolders()
    for each(VcFolder in VcFolders)
    {
        if (VcFolder.sdkConnection.name.match(dc.sdkConnection.name))
        {
            if (VcFolder.name == "vm") 
            {
                if (VcFolder.parent instanceof VcDatacenter) 
                {
                    if (VcFolder.parent.name == dc.name)
                    {   
                        var parentFolder = VcFolder;
                        for each (child in parentFolder.childEntity)
                        {
                            if (child.vimType == "Folder")
                            {
                                var current = child.parent
                                var path = child.name
                                do {
                                    var parent = current
                                    if (parent.name != "vm")
                                    {
                                        path = parent.name + "\\" + path
                                    }
                                    current = current.parent
                                } while (current.parent != null)
                                row.push({
                                    Name: child.name,
                                    Path: path
                                })
                                for each (child1 in child.childEntity)
                                {
                                    if (child1.vimType == "Folder")
                                    {
                                        var current = child1.parent
                                        var path1 = child1.name
                                        do {
                                            var parent = current
                                            if (parent.name != "vm")
                                            {
                                                path1 = parent.name + "\\" + path1
                                            }
                                            current = current.parent
                                        } while (current.parent != null)
                                        row.push({
                                            Name: child1.name,
                                            Path: path1
                                        })
                                        for each (child2 in child1.childEntity)
                                        {
                                            if (child2.vimType == "Folder")
                                            {
                                                var current = child2.parent
                                                var path2 = child2.name
                                                do {
                                                    var parent = current
                                                    if (parent.name != "vm")
                                                    {
                                                        path2 = parent.name + "\\" + path2
                                                    }
                                                    current = current.parent
                                                } while (current.parent != null)
                                                row.push({
                                                    Name: child2.name,
                                                    Path: path2
                                                })
                                                for each (child3 in child2.childEntity)
                                                {
                                                    if (child3.vimType == "Folder")
                                                    {
                                                        var current = child3.parent
                                                        var path3 = child3.name
                                                        do {
                                                            var parent = current
                                                            if (parent.name != "vm")
                                                            {
                                                                path3 = parent.name + "\\" + path3
                                                            }
                                                            current = current.parent
                                                        } while (current.parent != null)
                                                        row.push({
                                                            Name: child3.name,
                                                            Path: path3
                                                        })
                                                        for each (child4 in child3.childEntity)
                                                        {
                                                            if (child4.vimType == "Folder")
                                                            {
                                                                var current = child4.parent
                                                                var path4 = child4.name
                                                                do {
                                                                    var parent = current
                                                                    if (parent.name != "vm")
                                                                    {
                                                                        path4 = parent.name + "\\" + path4
                                                                    }
                                                                    current = current.parent
                                                                } while (current.parent != null)
                                                                row.push({
                                                                    Name: child4.name,
                                                                    Path: path4
                                                                })
                                                                for each (child5 in child4.childEntity)
                                                                {
                                                                    if (child5.vimType == "Folder")
                                                                    {
                                                                        var current = child5.parent
                                                                        var path5 = child5.name
                                                                        do {
                                                                            var parent = current
                                                                            if (parent.name != "vm")
                                                                            {
                                                                                path5 = parent.name + "\\" + path5
                                                                            }
                                                                            current = current.parent
                                                                        } while (current.parent != null)
                                                                        row.push({
                                                                            Name: child5.name,
                                                                            Path: path5
                                                                        })
                                                                        for each (child6 in child5.childEntity)
                                                                        {
                                                                            if (child6.vimType == "Folder")
                                                                            {
                                                                                var current = child6.parent
                                                                                var path6 = child6.name
                                                                                do {
                                                                                    var parent = current
                                                                                    if (parent.name != "vm")
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        path6 = parent.name + "\\" + path6
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    current = current.parent
                                                                                } while (current.parent != null)
                                                                                row.push({
                                                                                    Name: child6.name,
                                                                                    Path: path6
                                                                                })
                                                                                for each (child7 in child6.childEntity)
                                                                                {
                                                                                    if (child7.vimType == "Folder")
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        var current = child7.parent
                                                                                        var path6 = child7.name
                                                                                        do {
                                                                                            var parent = current
                                                                                            if (parent.name != "vm")
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                path7 = parent.name + "\\" + path7
                                                                                            }
                                                                                            current = current.parent
                                                                                        } while (current.parent != null)
                                                                                        row.push({
                                                                                            Name: child7.name,
                                                                                            Path: path7
                                                                                        })
                                                                                        for each (child8 in child7.childEntity)
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            if (child8.vimType == "Folder")
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                var current = child8.parent
                                                                                                var path6 = child8.name
                                                                                                do {
                                                                                                    var parent = current
                                                                                                    if (parent.name != "vm")
                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                        path8 = parent.name + "\\" + path8
                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                    current = current.parent
                                                                                                } while (current.parent != null)
                                                                                                row.push({
                                                                                                    Name: child8.name,
                                                                                                    Path: path8
                                                                                                })
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return row
}
vcs = VcPlugin.allSdkConnections
for each (vc in vcs)
{
    var dcs = vc.getAllDatacenters()
    for each (dc in dcs)
    {
        System.log("Getting folder path in '"+dc.name+"'...")
        var paths = getFolderPath(dc)   
        for (i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) 
        {
            System.log("Name:- " + paths[i].Name + " Path:- " + paths[i].Path);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have nested the sub-code eight times. Which is a bad practice as anytime there could be many more nested folders than 8 depending on the environment. I am trying to also append each child's parents into the "row" `array`, so not able to think how I can use a `do-while`.

Here's the expected output -

```
[2019-12-05 12:37:31.276] [I] Getting folder path in 'CHA-NX2'...
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.790] [I] Name:- Apps Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.792] [I] Name:- Test Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\Test
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.794] [I] Name:- HSD Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\Test\HSD
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.796] [I] Name:- CHD02 Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.798] [I] Name:- BlueZone Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\BlueZone Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.799] [I] Name:- Cactus Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\Cactus Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.801] [I] Name:- CognosTM1 Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\CognosTM1 Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.802] [I] Name:- Facets Beta Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\Facets Beta Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.804] [I] Name:- SAS Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\SAS Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.805] [I] Name:- SLX Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\SLX Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.807] [I] Name:- Facets5 Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\Facets5 Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.808] [I] Name:- DB2Apps Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\DB2Apps Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.810] [I] Name:- FHIA Test Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\FHIA Test Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.811] [I] Name:- ISTools Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\ISTools Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.813] [I] Name:- Infoserver Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\Infoserver Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.815] [I] Name:- Hedis 2018 Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\Hedis 2018 Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.816] [I] Name:- FireFox-Chrome Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\FireFox-Chrome Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.818] [I] Name:- Facets Test Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\Facets Test Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.819] [I] Name:- Facets Release2 Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\Facets Release2 Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.823] [I] Name:- PSF Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\PSF Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.825] [I] Name:- Prism Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\Prism Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.827] [I] Name:- CCPulse Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\CCPulse Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.829] [I] Name:- Facets TSIT Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\Facets TSIT Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.831] [I] Name:- Facets Release Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\Facets Release Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.833] [I] Name:- Hedis 2019 Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\Hedis 2019 Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.834] [I] Name:- Facets SUBS Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\Facets SUBS
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.836] [I] Name:- TeamMate Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\TeamMate Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.837] [I] Name:- Standard Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\Standard Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.839] [I] Name:- Facets 2016 Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\Facets 2016 Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.841] [I] Name:- Facets Prod2 Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\Facets Prod2 Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.842] [I] Name:- FHIA DEV Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\FHIA DEV Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.844] [I] Name:- Facets Development Servers Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\CHD02\Facets Development Servers
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.846] [I] Name:- Templates Path:- CHA-NX2\Apps\Templates
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.847] [I] Name:- Discovered virtual machine Path:- CHA-NX2\Discovered virtual machine
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.849] [I] Name:- Desktops Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.850] [I] Name:- Persistent Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.852] [I] Name:- Win10 1809 x64 Developer Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Win10 1809 x64 Developer
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.853] [I] Name:- Win10 1809 x64 Java Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Win10 1809 x64 Java
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.855] [I] Name:- Win10 1809 x64 Standard Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Win10 1809 x64 Standard
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.857] [I] Name:- Win10 1709 x64 Java Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Win10 1709 x64 Java
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.859] [I] Name:- Imaging EWS Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Imaging EWS
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.861] [I] Name:- Allan H Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Imaging EWS\Allan H
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.863] [I] Name:- David F Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Imaging EWS\David F
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.865] [I] Name:- Jack JC Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Imaging EWS\Jack JC
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.867] [I] Name:- Melville P Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Imaging EWS\Melville P
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.869] [I] Name:- Swetha B Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Imaging EWS\Swetha B
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.871] [I] Name:- Raja T Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Imaging EWS\Raja T
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.873] [I] Name:- Tim C Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Imaging EWS\Tim C
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.875] [I] Name:- Peter A Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Imaging EWS\Peter A
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.876] [I] Name:- Lee G Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Imaging EWS\Lee G
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.878] [I] Name:- Sai KV Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Imaging EWS\Sai KV
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.880] [I] Name:- Shane M Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Imaging EWS\Shane M
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.882] [I] Name:- Vjay E Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Imaging EWS\Vjay E
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.884] [I] Name:- Win10 1709 x64 Developer Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Win10 1709 x64 Developer
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.886] [I] Name:- Templates Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Templates
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.888] [I] Name:- Archive Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Templates\Archive
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.890] [I] Name:- Maintenance Devices Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Templates\Maintenance Devices
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.892] [I] Name:- Win10 x64 Standard Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Win10 x64 Standard
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.894] [I] Name:- Connect2Dev.com Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Connect2Dev.com
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.896] [I] Name:- Win7 x86 Developer Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Win7 x86 Developer
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.897] [I] Name:- Win7 x64 Developer Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Win7 x64 Developer
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.899] [I] Name:- Win10 x64 Java Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Win10 x64 Java
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.900] [I] Name:- Win7 x64 IIB Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Win7 x64 IIB
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.902] [I] Name:- Win10 Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Win10
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.903] [I] Name:- 7.12 Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\7.12
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.905] [I] Name:- Win7 x64 RAD Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Win7 x64 RAD
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.906] [I] Name:- Win7 x86 Standard Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Win7 x86 Standard
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.908] [I] Name:- Win10 1703 x64 Standard Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Win10 1703 x64 Standard
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.909] [I] Name:- Win10 x64 Developer Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Win10 x64 Developer
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.911] [I] Name:- Win7 x64 Standard Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Persistent\Win7 x64 Standard
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.912] [I] Name:- Provisioned Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Provisioned
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.914] [I] Name:- Windows 10 Deep Security Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Provisioned\Windows 10 Deep Security
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.916] [I] Name:- PackagingVMs Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Provisioned\PackagingVMs
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.917] [I] Name:- Windows 10 Standard Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Provisioned\Windows 10 Standard
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.919] [I] Name:- Windows 7 Dakota Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Provisioned\Windows 7 Dakota
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.920] [I] Name:- New Folder Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Provisioned\Windows 7 Dakota\New Folder
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.922] [I] Name:- Windows 7 eCopy Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Provisioned\Windows 7 eCopy
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.924] [I] Name:- Windows 7 Pilot Desktops Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Provisioned\Windows 7 Pilot Desktops
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.926] [I] Name:- Windows 7 Standard - Appsense Test Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Provisioned\Windows 7 Standard - Appsense Test
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.928] [I] Name:- Windows 7 Hedis Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Provisioned\Windows 7 Hedis
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.929] [I] Name:- Windows 7 Standard DSA Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Provisioned\Windows 7 Standard DSA
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.931] [I] Name:- Windows 7 Standard - Verint Dev Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Provisioned\Windows 7 Standard - Verint Dev
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.933] [I] Name:- Windows 7 Standard OfficeScan Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Provisioned\Windows 7 Standard OfficeScan
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.935] [I] Name:- Windows 10 SQA Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Provisioned\Windows 10 SQA
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.937] [I] Name:- Temp Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Temp
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.939] [I] Name:- BSOD Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Temp\BSOD
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.941] [I] Name:- Templates Path:- CHA-NX2\Desktops\Templates
[2019-12-05 12:37:50.943] [I] Getting folder path in 'CHA-N02'...
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.140] [I] Name:- ALL BCBST Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.142] [I] Name:- CareAdvance Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\CareAdvance
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.143] [I] Name:- Citrix Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Citrix
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.145] [I] Name:- Health Mason Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Citrix\Health Mason
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.147] [I] Name:- Infrastructure Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Citrix\Infrastructure
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.148] [I] Name:- Controllers Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Citrix\Infrastructure\Controllers
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.150] [I] Name:- Admin Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Citrix\Infrastructure\Admin
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.151] [I] Name:- Director Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Citrix\Infrastructure\Director
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.153] [I] Name:- License Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Citrix\Infrastructure\License
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.154] [I] Name:- Provisioning Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Citrix\Infrastructure\Provisioning
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.156] [I] Name:- LoginVSI Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Citrix\Infrastructure\LoginVSI
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.158] [I] Name:- ShareFile Controllers Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Citrix\Infrastructure\ShareFile Controllers
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.159] [I] Name:- FAS Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Citrix\Infrastructure\FAS
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.161] [I] Name:- StoreFront Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Citrix\Infrastructure\StoreFront
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.162] [I] Name:- Disaster Recovery Servers Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Disaster Recovery Servers
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.164] [I] Name:- Dynamics Servers Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Dynamics Servers
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.165] [I] Name:- Enterprise Monitoring Servers Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Enterprise Monitoring Servers
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.167] [I] Name:- Fax Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Fax
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.169] [I] Name:- Fax Servers Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Fax Servers
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.170] [I] Name:- File Servers Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\File Servers
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.172] [I] Name:- ICD10 Servers Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\ICD10 Servers
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.173] [I] Name:- Imaging Servers Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Imaging Servers
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.175] [I] Name:- Active Directory Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Active Directory
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.177] [I] Name:- bcbstbeta.com Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Active Directory\bcbstbeta.com
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.178] [I] Name:- bcbstdev.com Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Active Directory\bcbstdev.com
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.180] [I] Name:- bcbst.com Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Active Directory\bcbst.com
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.181] [I] Name:- bcbstsit.com Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Active Directory\bcbstsit.com
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.183] [I] Name:- bcbsttest.com Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Active Directory\bcbsttest.com
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.185] [I] Name:- dmz.bcbst.com Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Active Directory\dmz.bcbst.com
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.186] [I] Name:- nonprod.com Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Active Directory\nonprod.com
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.188] [I] Name:- sdmz.bcbst.com Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Active Directory\sdmz.bcbst.com
[2019-12-05 12:38:02.190] [I] Name:- Facets Servers Path:- CHA-N02\ALL BCBST\Facets Servers
```

Comment: Java or JavaScript?

Comment: please add the data as well which you iterate. please add the wanted result as object/array.

Comment: what is `for each(VcFolder in VcFolders)` doing? it is not javascript.

Comment: @NinaScholz I was just going to ask the same, really. I looked up if it's not some new Java syntax I'm not aware of.

Comment: This is JS. I have attached a pic showing the data which I am iterating. The wanted result should be in an array of objects called "row" @NinaScholz

Comment: for a start the first 4 ifs could be combined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an abstract approach (i still doubt, that the code is Javascript not Java).

This is a pattern of yopur code, where you iterate some data, check the type and iterate a path. At the end you put a new object to `row`.

```
for (child in parentFolder.childEntity) { // *in* maybe wrong, just to mention ...
    if (child.vimType == "Folder") {
        var current = child.parent
        var path = child.name
        do {
            var parent = current
            if (parent.name != "vm") path = parent.name + "\\" + path;
            current = current.parent
        } while (current.parent != null)
        row.push({ Name: child.name, Path: path });
         // next same pattern with child.childEntity
    }
}
```

You could transform this pattern to a function andhand over the data for iterating and the target array `row` (or maybe not, if a this is a nested function).

Then take a negated check and continue the loop without haveing a nested block.

Then get the path value and push the object.

Finally exit the recursive call or call the function again with new data. In you code, you stof the nested approach, here, you could check if `child.childEntity` is falsy.

```
function iter(data, row) {
    for (child in data) {

        if (child.vimType !== "Folder") continue;

        var current = child.parent
        var path = child.name

        do {
            var parent = current;
            if (parent.name !== "vm") path = parent.name + "\\" + path;
            current = current.parent
        } while (current.parent != null)

        row.push({ Name: child.name, Path: path });

        if (!child.childEntity) continue;

        iter(child.childEntity, row);
    }
}

// call
iter(parentFolder.childEntity, row);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! @NinaScholz.
I am kinda embarrassed as to why I couldn't think of doing a nested function call by myself. Sometimes you just need someone else to point the obvious!